# ASP.NET countdown timer (hours, minutes, seconds)

Tags: asp.net, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I have to make a countdown timer where you choose the amount of seconds, minutes & hours for the timer to countdown. I found a video (https://youtu.be/zgxV7LaoGAk?t=930) where this guy explains how everything works, but his timer doesn't include hours.

This is the code for a countdown timer with only minutes & seconds:

```
var currentMinutes = (newTime.Length > 2) ?
    int.Parse(newTime.Substring(0, newTime.Length - 2)) :
    0;

var currentSeconds = (newTime.Length > 2) ?
    int.Parse(newTime.Substring(newTime.Length - 2)) :
    int.Parse(newTime);
```

Could anyone tell me how to write the code for a countdown timer with seconds, minutes AND hours (var currentHours ?)

```
var currentHours = ...


var currentMinutes = (newTime.Length > 2) ?
    int.Parse(newTime.Substring(0, newTime.Length - 2)) :
    0;

var currentSeconds = (newTime.Length > 2) ?
    int.Parse(newTime.Substring(newTime.Length - 2)) :
    int.Parse(newTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so how to do this?

Well, we can do 100% server side code - great if you stuck - don't know JavaScript

So, say we drop in 3 labels

Drop in 3 text boxes.

Drop in a timer control.

Drop in 4 buttons - (see later how we use them).

we have this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div style="width:350px;padding:20px">

    <div style="margin:auto">

        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text="Hours" Font-Size="Larger" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" Text="0" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tbox"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMin" runat="server" Text="Minutes" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMin" runat="server" Text="0" CssClass="tbox" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:15px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblsec" runat="server" Text="Seconds" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSec" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Text="5" CssClass="tbox" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;height:15px"></div>

        <div style="margin:auto">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" Text="Start" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdStop" runat="server" Text="Stop" style="margin-left:20px" />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdStartJS" runat="server" Text="Start JS" style="margin-left:20px"
                OnClientClick="mystart();return false" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdStopJS" runat="server" Text="Stop JS" style="margin-left:20px"
                OnClientClick="mystop();return false"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblDone" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
```

And our code will look like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click

    ' take entered values - convert to time
    Dim MyTime As DateTime
    MyTime = TimeSerial(txtHours.Text, txtMin.Text, txtSec.Text)

    ' save time value
    ViewState("MyTime") = MyTime

    Timer1.Interval = 1000  ' upddate every one second
    Timer1.Enabled = True   ' start the timer.
    lblDone.Text = "Started"
End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim myTime As DateTime = ViewState("MyTime")

    ' check if we are to stop
    If myTime <= TimeSerial(0, 0, 0) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False      ' turn off timer
        ' do whatever for end of timer
        lblDone.Text = "Done!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim OneSecond As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)

    myTime = myTime - OneSecond
    ' update text boxes
    txtHours.Text = myTime.Hour
    txtMin.Text = myTime.Minute
    txtSec.Text = myTime.Second

    ViewState("MyTime") = myTime

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

So the above is very similar to say desktop approach. (and like on desktop, we even dropped in that timer control).

The downside of course is this means a post-back for each 1 second.

But, we could surround the above markup with a update-panel - and it would be and look butter smooth.

The 2nd way:

100% Client side code.

So, with the above page, lets write the JavaScript code for the "js buttons"

We have this (I do assume this page has use of jQuery - but that's quite much assumed these days).

```
<script>

    MyTime = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0)
    TimeZero = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0)
    MyTimer = 0

    tH = $("#txtHours")
    tM = $("#txtMin")
    tS = $("#txtSec")

    function mystart() {

        MyTime.setHours(tH.val())
        MyTime.setMinutes(tM.val())
        MyTime.setSeconds(tS.val())

        if (MyTime > TimeZero) {
            MyTimer = setInterval(mytic,1000)
            $("#lblDone").text("Start")
        }
    }

    function mytic() {

        MyTime.setSeconds(MyTime.getSeconds() - 1)

        tH.val(MyTime.getHours())
        tM.val(MyTime.getMinutes())
        tS.val(MyTime.getSeconds())

        if (MyTime <= TimeZero) {
            clearInterval(MyTimer)
            $("#lblDone").text("Done !!!")
        }
    }

    function mystop() {
            clearInterval(MyTimer)
    }
</script>
```

So both the JavaScript, or the server side code does quite much the same thing.

The major difference you note is that the client side code?
It never hits the server side, and thus looks quite a bit smoother.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but you didn't answer my question

Comment: I posted TWO working versions of a count down timer that includes hours, minutes, and seconds. And you did not specify if you want 100% server side code and not having to write JavaScript. My first example does this. The 2nd example is a 100% client side code, again with a count down timer, and that example also includes hours in the display.  So I not sure what i am missing here? in fact, in EITHER case, we see the REALLLY huge trick is to use a a date/time var. This eliminates the need to write/mange  increment/decrement the hours, minutes, seconds, and thus will save buckets of code

Comment: I'm a beginner (this is my 1st ASP project) and I just wanted to know what this code means & does so that I could add hours to the countdown timer
(   var currentMinutes = (newTime.Length > 2) ?
    int.Parse(newTime.Substring(0, newTime.Length - 2)) :
    0;
)
I want to try the 1st working version that you replied with but I don't know where to put the 2nd part of the code (Protected sub ...). I assume that the 1st part of the code goes to a .aspx file, but where does the 2nd part go? - I tried aspx.cs and that didn't work. 
Thank you!

Comment: ok, I posted code for a web forms. It not clear if you using c#, or vb.net (not a huge deal), and also what kind of web project you created. (mvc project, or webforms). Web forms are now quite old, but they can be great if you are starting out. As noted, you have a choice to write this solution as 100% server side code, or you can write the code as JavaScript that will run "inside" of the browser. (thus the code runs on the users desktop and does not even require code behind). As to where code goes? Well, it is assume you can at least drop a button into the markup and have it call server code

Comment: So, you not provided some sample markup and what you attempted so far. So without at least some sample code + markup you attempted, then it was quite hard to guess what solution and advice will work for you, or is even appropriate. And it not clear if you wanting to avoid JavaScript, or are happy to use JavaScript. When starting out, I tend to stick to 100% server side code (code behind), since it clean c# or clean vb.net code. So it is a question of learning curve. Over time, then without question one will adopt and write more JavaScript, but starting out then server side code is easier

Comment: So, before you start doing fancy stuff, it is assumed you are able to say drop a simple button into a web page, and then have that button run code behind. This approach is VERY similar to desktop coding. (drop a button onto a form, then write some small event routine for that button).  You need at least this basic skill to drop buttons into the markup, and then when clicking on that button to run your code behind. This is very easy, but it still a basic skill you need to master. Once that simple button code works, then the first example above (100% server side code behind) is a good test/try

Comment: And in fact, it not clear if you prefer a c# solution, or a vb.net one. Or as the 2nd example shows, we did not use c# or vb.net, but only JavaScript code (which thus would work for c# or vb.net). So, you have 3 choices of language solutions here!! (hint: add c#, or vb.net tags to your question.  Also, I doubt that many here are willing to stop what they are doing and run off to watch some video.